# How to completely remove EnterpriseDB Installation of Postgresql on Ubuntu?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, postgresql-9.3, enterprisedb

All,

I'm trying to install/run PostgreSQL 9.3, but am receiving a multitude of errors which seem to point to a failed installation of postgresql from the enterpriseDB package.

For example, trying to start the server with this command:

`sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql-9.3 restart` (or start)

...yields the following:

```
Restarting PostgreSQL 9.3: 
-su: /opt/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/pg_ctl: No such file or directory
PostgreSQL 9.3 did not start in a timely fashion, please see /opt/PostgreSQL/9.3/data/pg_log/startup.log for details
```

Except there is no `/opt/PostgreSQL/` folder, and I've been told that creation of that was attempted during the EnterpriseDB installation...why the start command is trying to go there, I do not know!

I've [started another thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50906/why-wont-postgresql-9-3-start-on-ubuntu) which gave me a very temporary solution, but that doesn't seem to help after I do a restart of my machine.

**So the question**, how do I completely remove the EnterpriseDB failed installation?

I've tried these commands, but the issue still lingers:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove postgresql-9.3-postgis pgadmin3
sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql\*
```

Any thoughts or recommendations are welcome!

Thank you!

-m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Feb 2009, Scahin_S  wrote in [1] to use the uninstall-postgresql binary.  In the same thread Sachin_S also documented a manual alternative for uninstalling 8.3 is

```
/opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/installer/server/removeshortcuts.sh /opt/PostgreSQL/8.3 8.3 
/etc/init.d postgresql-8.3 stop 
rm -rf /opt/PostgreSQL 
rm /etc/postgres-reg.ini 
rm -rf /etc/init.d/postgresql-8.3 
userdel postgres 

if /etc/ld.so.conf exists, edit it and remove /opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/lib 
if present. 

if /etc/ld.so.conf.d exists: 

rm /etc/ld.so.conf.d/postgresql-8.3.conf
```

1 - "Uninstall Postgres" thread
Enterprise DB "PostgreSQL Installers for Windows, Linux and OS X" forum
http://forums.enterprisedb.com/posts/list/1437.page

Answer (score 2):

I accidentally deleted my passwd file under `/etc` directory and after that postgresql service could start, 
when I run command `systemctl status postgresql.myversion.` the error was

```
no passwd entry found for user postgres
```

I decided to reinstall postgresql. Because I used enterpricedb installer

`sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql*` did not work for me.

In my case uninstaller was under `/opt/PostgreSQL/9.5/`. cd here and

`sudo ./uninstall-postgresql` then reinstall using enterpricedb, installer recreated `postgres` user and problem solved

may help someone else

Comment: :) you are wellcome